# Provide a ref to inject it in a child component with Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Anybody knows how to `provide` a ref to child components. For example:

`Parent` component provide the ref:

```
<template>
  <div ref="myRef" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchContainer',
  provide: {
    parentRef: this.$refs.myRef
  }
}
</script>

</style>
```

And `Child` component inject it:

```
<template>
  <div />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchCard',
  inject: ['parentRef']
}
</script>

</style>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking into using slots?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to change the style of the `parent` component in the `child`. (without using a `getElementById`)

Comment: I want to hide the parent when the child is open (the child is a modal and the parent a list)

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. If a certain event in the child should cause changes in the parent component, then you should emit the event and let the parent component itself handle what to do with the event.

Comment: yes I can emit an event or pass the ref as a prop, but I wanted to know if it's possible to provide a ref

Answer (score 1):

Generally the interaction between parent and child component should be done using props and emitted events :

```
<template>
  <div />
</template>

<script>
export default {
 
  methods:{
      changeParentStyle(){
            this.$emit('change-style')
       }
  }
}
</script>

</style>
```

parent :

```
<template>
  <child @change-style="changeStyle" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchContainer',
   methods:{
      changeStyle(){
          //change the property that affects your style
       }
   }
}
</script>

</style>
```

Comment: yeah thx for the answer, it's the best possibility but I wanted to know how to provide a ref. With React I think it's possible to 'provide' a ref with the context I think

Comment: even that works using ref and provide/inject it should be considered as bad practice

Comment: provide/inject is used rarely to communicate between a grandparent and grandchild components and this has some reactivity issues

Answer (score 1):

I have manage to achieve providing ref to children. But in my opinion if you want to communicate betwwen parent and children I think you have got your answer already by Boussadjra Brahim.

Still providing ref has its own use cases. I am usinig it for dialogs.

Here is my solution:

```
<!-- Parent Component -->

<template>
    <div ref="myRef"></div>
  </template>
  
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'SearchContainer',
    methods:{
        getMyRef(){
            return this.$refs.myRef
        }
    },
    provide() {
      return{
        parentRef: this.getMyRef
    }
    }
  }
</script>


<!-- Child Component -->

<template>
    <div></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'SearchContainer',
    methods:{
        useRef(){
            this.parentRef().data // Can access data properties
            this.parentRef().method() // can access methods
        }
    }
    inject: ['parentRef']
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Or in provide you can pass it like this: `return { parentRef: () => this.$refs.myRef }`

Comment: Yes, It would be avoid unnecessary method definition.